# R: Column Headers as ylim and Row Names as xlim in R

Tags: r, plot, visualization, analysis

I have my data as follows:

```
Date           Medicine1     Medicine2     Medicine3     Medicine4
2014-01-01     0.986         0.897         0.765         0.566
2014-02-01     0.989         0.888         0.778         0.587
2014-03-01     0.991         0.867         0.788         0.565
2014-04-01     0.982         0.883         0.771         0.532
2014-05-01     0.995         0.873         0.799         0.588
```

I am using matplot( ) function to plot the above data. Following is my code:

```
med_temp = as.matrix(Medicine[,2:(length(Medicine[1,]))])
matplot(med_temp, type = c("b"), pch = 1, col = 2:(length(Medicine[1,])))
```

Following is the plot:

[image: Med_plot]

I would want the Column Headers as ylim and Date column as xlim. I tried using

```
ylim = as.vector("Medicine1","Medicine2","Medicine3","Medicine4") and
ylim = c("Medicine1","Medicine2","Medicine3","Medicine4")
```

Both of these are giving me errors. What do I do to get in the format I want? Is there a way to do it?

Thanks in advance for the help

Real Data :

```
Month      Retention1     Diff
Month1      100.0          0.0
Month2       95.5         -4.5
Month3       90.6         -4.9
Month4       85.9         -4.7
Month5       82.0         -3.9
```

Comment: Do you mean `xlab` and `ylab`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're playing around with the wrong parameter here. `ylim=` and `xlim=` are for controlling the range of values along an axis, they have nothing to do with labeling the axis. So maybe you want something like

```
med_temp = as.matrix(Medicine[,2:(length(Medicine[1,]))])
matplot(med_temp, type = c("b"), pch = 1, col = 2:(length(Medicine[1,])), xaxt="n")

axis(1, at=1:nrow(med_temp), labels=Medicine$Date)
axis(4, at=med_temp[nrow(med_temp), ],labels=colnames(med_temp), 4)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks MrFlick!! This is what I wanted to achieve. I was able to get the numbers on the left but not the names for the lines that you showed on the right. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This was working on the test data that I published here. When I apply to my actual data, I am getting a warning message : "xant" is not a graphical parameter (when I execute the first and second lines of code -- equivalent of med_temp and matplot(...) here). Do you happen to know why I am getting that? Thanks!

Comment: The message is for "xant"? That probably should be "xaxt", right?

Comment: It is "xant" in the warning message

Comment: Well, I don't know what that means. Unless you can provide sample data that reproduces the problem, i'm not sure what to tell you. I can only help with errors I can reproduce. Try to figure out how your real data is different than what you've posted.

Comment: I have updated my question with sample of real data. Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

I think better here to plot with axes (`axes=F`) and just annotate your plot using `text`. You can also add a proper legend using `legend`.

[image]

```
cols <- seq_len(ncol(med_temp))
matplot(med_temp, type = c("b"), pch = 1, col=cols,axes=FALSE)
text(1.5,med_temp[1,],labels = colnames(med_temp),col=cols,srt=10)
axis(1,at=1:5,labels=Medicine$Date)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use ggplot for this:

```
mm = melt(ddf)
ggplot(mm, aes(x=Date, y=value, group=variable, color=variable))+geom_line()+geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: don't forget to import  `reshape2` and `ggplot2`.